# A basis of the symmetric power consisting of powers

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, polynomials

I have [asked this question on math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356925/a-basis-of-the-symmetric-power-consisting-of-powers), but did not get an answer - I was quite surprised because I thought that lots of people must have though about this before:

Let $V$ be a complex vector space with basis $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in V$. Denote by $v_1\odot\cdots\odot v_k$ the image of $v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_k$ in the symmetric power $\newcommand{\Sym}{\mathrm{Sym}}\Sym^k(V)$. It is well-known that the Elements $v^{\odot k}$  for $v\in V$ generate this space (see, for instance, [this answer on math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137912/can-e-n-always-be-written-as-a-linear-combination-of-n-th-powers-of-linear-p/138411#138411)), so they must contain a basis.

In other words, let $N=\binom{n+k-1}k$, then there must be $v_1,\ldots,v_N\in V$ with 
$$\mathrm{Sym}^k V = \mathbb Cv_1^{\odot k} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb C v_N^{\odot k}.$$
I am looking for an explicit description of such a basis. Is such a description known? Is there maybe even a *"nice"* or somewhat *"natural"* choice for the $v_i$ as linear combinations of the $x_i$?

Comment: The best reason I know of that powers of linear forms span $Sym^k(V)$ is that $Sym^k(V)$ is an irreducible $GL(V)$-module. Hence, the orbit of any particular (non-zero) power must span the entire space. After choosing the standard basis for $V$ as $e_1,\dots,e_n$ and viewing $GL(V)$ as square matrices, a highest weight vector for $Sym^k(V)$ is $e_1^k$. Hence, to obtain a basis one only needs to apply lowering operators to this element (which are lower triangular matrices). The proper choice of lowering operators will yield a basis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would look up a book on the calculus of finite differences in a multivariate setting.
The claim here is to show that for any multi-index $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$
of length $k$ one can express the multiple derivative at zero
$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)^\alpha \ 
(t_1x_1+\cdots+ t_n x_n)^k
$$
as a linear combination of finite difference analogous expressions
which should only involve the evaluation of $(t_1x_1+\cdots+ t_n x_n)^k$
at integer points $(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ with nonnegative coordinates adding up
to $k$. This is the same as the above candidate basis considered by you and Peter.
I don't know if there exists a multivariate analogue of the [Newton series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference). If so
then this would immediately imply the wanted statement.

---

Edit:
Apparently there is such a formula due to Lascoux and Schutzenberger, see Theorem 9.6.1 page 148 in the book
"Symmetric functions and combinatorial operators on polynomials" by Alain Lascoux.
Another source on the web is [here](http://phalanstere.univ-mlv.fr/~al/ARTICLES/NewtonInterp.ps.gz). It also has the required property here which is that the number of finite differences taken is the same as the degree of the multiplying Schubert polynomial.

---

Edit: @Jesko you're right it is a bit more complicated than what I said. Also, the Lascoux-Schutzenberger formula might not be the simplest to use here.

First note that expressions
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (x_i-x_n)^{\beta_i}\ \times\ (kx_n)^{k-|\beta|}\ ,
$$
where $\beta$ ranges over multiindices with $n-1$ components and length $|\beta|\le k$,
form a basis.
Now you get the latter as derivatives
$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)^{\beta} \ 
\left(t_1x_1+\cdots+ t_{n-1} x_{n-1}+\left(k-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}t_i\right)x_n\right)^k
$$
at $t=0$.

Call $f(t_1,\ldots,t_{n-1})$ the polynomial function to be hit with derivatives.
One has a multivariate Newton expansion for it:
$$
f(t)=\sum_{m} (t-a)^m \partial^m f(a_{11},a_{21},\ldots,a_{n-1,1})
$$
as follows.
Here $a$ stands for a matrix of indeterminates $(a_{ij})$ with $1\le i\le n-1$
and $1\le j\le d$, with $d$ high enough.
Let $\partial_{ij}$ denote the divided difference operator acting on functions of these indeterminates
as
$$
\partial_{ij} g=\frac{1}{a_{i,j+1}-a_{ij}}\left(
g({\rm argument\ with\ }a_{i,j+1}\ {\rm and}\ a_{ij}\ {\rm exchanged})- g
\right)\ .
$$
The notation $m=(m_1,\ldots,m_{n-1})$ is for a multiindex with nonnegative entries.
We also write the corresponding operator
$$
\partial^m = \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \left(\partial_{i, m_i}
\cdots\partial_{i,2}\partial_{i,1}\right)
$$
noting that finite difference operators concerning different groups of variables commute.
Finally 
$$
(t-a)^m=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \left((t_i-a_{i,m_i})\cdots(t_i-a_{i,2})(t_i-a_{i,1})\right)\ .
$$
The formula basically amounts to applying Newton's univariate formula in each coordinate direction separately.
Now use this with the choice $a_{i,j}=j-1$, then take the beta derivative in the $t$'s
and that should be it.

Comment: Hey! This sounds like a really great approach, but I must confess I do not see (at all) how the formula in Theorem 9.6.1 implies the claim that all the $(\sum_i \alpha_i x_i)^k$ form a basis of the degree-$k$ polynomials. Would you mind giving a little more detail? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Jesko: see my last edit.

Comment: I still didn't find the time to go through all the details, but I think I got the general idea now, and this answer should definitely be accepted. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Can you work with polarization?

$2 x_1x_2 = (x_1-x_2)^2 -x_1^2-x_2^2$.

If $k=2$ then $(x_i+x_j)^2$ for $i\le j$ is already a basis. 

In general,
$(x_{i_1}+\dots +x_{i_k})^k$ for $1\le i_1\le\dots\le i_k\le n$ might do the job.

Comment: That's basically the elements from the proof I referenced, but for $k>2$ it requires more than $\binom{n+k-1}k$ terms, namely all the $(x_{i_1}+\cdots+x_{i_j})^k$ for $2\le j\le k$. It's not obvious to me why only the ones for $j=k$ should suffice.

Comment: Is not $(x_1+x_1+x_2)^3$ as good as $(x_1+x_2)^3$?

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong, these elements were my first choice as well and I very much believe that they work, but I can't prove it.