# Is the ideal of the Veronese variety $V_{d,n}$ generated by quadrics?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, projective-geometry, classical-invariant-theory

Maybe it sounds like a silly question to the experts but I'm not able to find a proper reference in the web. Anyone knows if the ideal $I_{d,n}$ of the Veronese variety $V_{d,n}$ is generated by quadrics for all $d$ and $n$? If not, are there any bounds on $d,n$ for which the generation is known?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that is true.  I have a vague recollection that Dolgachev deduces this from his analysis of the "symbolic method" in his book on invariant theory.  Anyway, I assigned it as a homework exercise in an algebraic geometry course many years ago, and you can find is as the typed solution to Problem 11 here: https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~jstarr/M589s20/725aps3soln.pdf

Comment: @JasonStarr  Thank you very much, wonderful!

Comment: the answer is yes and a proof is given here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351528/ideal-of-rational-normal-curve-of-degree-d/351566#351566

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Yes, I heard a lecture by J. M. Landsberg recently where he used the quadratic defining equations of various analogues of Veronese embeddings to give a purely geometric proof of the classification of semisimple complex Lie groups.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Interesting. I didn't know about this approach to the Lie group classification. The only nonstandard approach I was aware of is that of Mohamed EL Houari https://www.theses.fr/1994PA112366 as well as Predrag Cvitanovic https://birdtracks.eu/

Comment: I should have also mentioned Eugenios Angelopoulos.

Comment: @JasonStarr : you may be referring to this paper : https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9902102?

Comment: @Libli.  Yes, that is the exact reference.  I started to look for it yesterday, but got sidetracked by something else.